# Selecting the anchor tag inside the child div of a div

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML. I want to implement jQuery to add href attribute to each readmore link. I want to know how can I select the readmore links here. The readmore links are generated dynamically and **I want to give different values to each readmore link**.Is there any way? I have tried using this.

**Update**

**I want to get the a tag inside the first child of .content...How to get it...???**

```
jQuery('.content.c7:nth-child(1)').attr('href','www.google.com');
```

but it didnt work. What am i doing wrong here? please help me.

```
 <div class="content c7">
        <div class="products">
            <div id="post_content">
                Hai
            </div>
            <div class="end readmore">
                <a >Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="products">
            <div id="post_content">
                hello
            </div>
            <div class="end readmore">
                <a>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="products">
            <div id="post_content">
                how are you
            </div>
            <a >Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="products">
            <div id="post_content">
                I am fine
            </div>
            <div class="end readmore">
                <a>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I answered the "different values for each" bit below.

Comment: check my answer i have updated according to new needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.content.c7 .readmore a').attr('href','www.google.com');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eetK/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('.content.c7 .readmore a').each(function (index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        // Set href for the first element
        $(this).attr('href', 'www.google.com');
    } else if (index == 1) {
        // Set href for the second element
        $(this).attr('href', 'www.yourlink.com');
    }
    // Similarly set href for other elements individually
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eetK/1/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('.content.c7 .readmore:eq(0) a').attr('href','www.google.com');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eetK/2/)

Comment: As i said the readmore is generated dynamically and i want to give different href to each readmore link

Answer (score 0):

For all the "read more" links, you'd select something like:

```
var rmlinks = jQuery('.content.c7 .readmore a');
```

If you want to set them all to the same thing, you can do so via:

```
rmlinks.attr('href', 'http://example.com');
```

If you want to hit them one-by-one based on a list of hrefs you have elsewhere, then:

```
for ( i = 0; i < rmlinks.length; ++i )
{
  var newhref = "???";  // up to you
  $(rmlinks[i]).attr('href', newhref);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new Code Working Demohttp://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vZnUU/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var links = ["www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.fb.com","www.hotmail.com"];
    i =0;
    $('.products a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', links[i]);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vZnUU/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.products div a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href','www.google.com');
    });
});
```

if you want to change link only if the text is Read More

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vZnUU/1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.products div a').each(function () {
        if($(this).text() == 'Read More')
        $(this).attr('href','www.google.com');
    });
});
```

Comment: you want to change link only if the text is Read More ??? for that i have updated the code

Comment: Not like that. I want to change the link of each readmore  class but href off those is different.I assume you understood what i said...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following structure

```
<div class="content c7">
    <div id="product_1" class="products">
        <div id="post_content">
            Hai
        </div>
        <div class="end readmore">
            <a >Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I think this is what you want:

```
$('.content.c7 .products').each(function() {
    var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).find('.readmore > a').attr('href', 'www.google.com/' + the_id);
});
```

NB: you should NOT use the same id multiple times (`post_content` for instance)